# Plotting a sequence of xy coordinates in Matlab. Can I make the colour get darker as the sequence progresses?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I have a set of xy coordinates in a matrix `X = [x1,x2,... ; y1,y2,...]`. The points come from finding the root of a function iteratively. I'd like to plot each coordinate on a Cartesian grid, but ideally have some way to distinguish the earlier coordinates from the later one. So for example, if I could plot each point, and have the colour get a bit darker with each point, then the viewer would be able to see how the points actually do converge. Is there a way to specify this somehow?

Comment: You can try the solution proposed in [documentaation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/2383/undocumented-features/7849/color-coded-2d-line-plots-with-color-data-in-third-dimension#t=201703051755076393877)

Answer (score 0):

There should be so many ways to do this, as it is a simple task, BTW.

*Example*:

```
hold on
k = 0;
while (true)
    k = k+1;
    if k == 10; break; end                % just to stop loop
    r = k/10;                             % something linked to the found root 
    plot(k,k,'*','Color',[r,r,r]);        % your plot
end
```

So basically, you link `r` to the found `root` or to something that shows the distance from the `root`.
This solution should give you idea, hopefully.

[image]